# phpmyadmin can't connect to mariadb in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect a phpmyadmin container to a nginx container with mariadb downloaded.
I can access to phpmyadmin web site, but I can't log in to.
An error code `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` and `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused` will appear.
I made a bridge network "test-net", and connected the phpmyadmin container and the nginx container to the network. I commanded `docker run -d --name phpmyadmin -e PMA_HOST=web -e PMA_PORT=3306 -p 8081:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` for the phpmyadmin. Web is the nginx container and 3306 is my mariadb port number.
How can I log in to my database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Can you connect to the MariaDB instance using the command line tools and the username/password you're trying to use? Is the user's host value set to allow it to connect from phpMyAdmin (with hose `%` or the IP address/host name, etc)?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I can connect to the MariaDB using the command line tools. I only set my host value "web" to the phpmyadmin server name form and PMA_HOST=web in docker run commend. But, I can connect to the MariaDB using "docker --link" followed by https://migueldoctor.medium.com/run-mysql-phpmyadmin-locally-in-3-steps-using-docker-74eb735fa1fc. I know --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker, so I try to search about --link flag because I could find any other solutions. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You need to ensure that the MariaDB user also allows external connections; can you run the command `select User, Host from mysql.user;` on your MariaDB instance and report back the results for the user you're using (it might be more than one line, or it might only be one line)? It might also help to show us how you're creating that user (which part of the process and what SQL commands).

Comment: @IsaacBennetch The command result shows User:root and Host:localhost. I haven't set about mysql users before. So, I have to set any permission of external connection?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I can access phpmyadmin instance! I changed bind-address 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in the mariadb cnf file and created User'root' and Host'mariadb-host-ip-address' in mariadb instance.